# Custom Terminal App ID

Tags: gnome-terminal, matlab, window-management

I am running Matlab through the terminal, with the `-nodesktop` and `-nosplash` flags. I even created a custom laucher with `gnome-terminal -e "matlab -nodesktop -nosplash"`. However, the OS (Ubuntu 12.10) recognizes it as just another terminal window.

Is it possible to somehow assign a different process ID and title to that particular terminal window (with maybe a specific icon), so that it can be seen as a separate applications, which I can travel to simply with `Alt+Tab`, and which the OS doesn't group with the rest of terminal windows?

Comment: You can try to assign a different class & name to the gnome-terminal in your launcher. Maybe this helps http://askubuntu.com/questions/341900/whyre-two-separate-panel-icons-when-opened-grouping-under-the-same-icon/344455#344455

Comment: That classifies as an answer...  Why don't you write it up as one so the asker can then close the question so that other users don't have to read (yet another) question answered in a comment?  ;-)